# Center text inside image dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have a container div where height and width are set to 100% and position is relative.  Inside the div I center an image (image is smaller than div) using display: block and margin:auto.  Then I am attempting to center text inside the image using position: absolute, left: 45%, top 82px.  Vertical alignment appears to be okay, but as the number of characters in text grows the text is no longer aligned in the middle.  So in my image below if text is 4 characters the text would no longer be centered.  Is there a better way to dynamically align text?

[image]

html:

```html
<div id="countup-container">
    <img id="countup-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YqKE.png" alt="Accident Free Days">    
    <span id="ctl00" class="countup-text">101</span>    
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```css
#countup-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#countup-image {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 240px;
}

.countup-text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 45.3%;
    top: 82px;
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant code or fiddle.

Comment: added relevant code

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd use an image in this case at all.  A couple lines of html could re-create that image, and then you can place the text exactly where you want it.  Sounds like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me (as a better question would have been "what's the best way to do this" instead of "I think it's best if I do this in this weird way,,, now how do I do that?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using absolute positioning to center it you would want to change your `left: 45%;` to `left: 50%;` then set a transform like this:

```
.thing_to_center_horizontal {
    top 82px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This will make it center even with dynamic content.

`left: 50%;` will put it in the center based on the top left corner of the content, then `transform: translateX(-50%);` will move it 50% of the content's width (this is the dynamic part) to the left making it center.

Make sense?

But maybe a simple `text-align: center;` might work, but its hard to tell because you did not post any code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you could simply add `text-align:center` to your `#countup-container`.

And remove `left:45%` to your `.countup-text`